# Fast looping through two lists comparing regex pattern using value from one list against values in another list

Tags: python, regex, performance, loops, intersection

I'm currently trying to deal with a tricky problem in Python.  To set the scene, I'm using Let's Encrypt, so I have the (posix)paths of the live directory and I have a list of domains from a CMS.

I'm trying to compare the domains against the paths, which requires a regular expression match containing the value from the first list, because the paths will contain the domain names, but I can't/don't understand how I would do a set intersection because the values don't match, but this is really painfully slow with a traditional for loop (when you have >12000 domain names and >10000 certificates (paths)).

So, some explanatory code:

```
import re

from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend, openssl


all_domains = function_that_returns_domains_as_list()
all_paths = function_that_returns_certificate_paths()
nocert_list = list()


def cert_check(path):
    cert = load_pem_x509_certificate(path.read_bytes(), default_backend())
    cur_date = datetime.now()
    end_date = cert.not_valid_after
    ... # More logic and functions for checking if the certificate has expired etc.


def path(domain):
    for path in all_paths:
        if path.match(f"*/{domain}*"):
            return path


def check_domain_certs():
    for domain in all_domains:
        path_check = path(domain)
        if not path_check:
            nocert_list.append(domain)
        if path_check:
            cert_path = path_check
            cert_check(cert_path)
```

Even if I don't call the cert_check function in the check_domain_certs function and instead add the path to a list, to call outside of the loop and the check_domain_certs function, the looping itself takes a long time (I ran it whilst typing out this message and it has only just finished some ~30 minutes later.  Probably something do do with it having to loop about 120 million times.)

I've run down a lot of stackoverflow rabbit holes today so I'm actually turning to the community for help this time.

Answer (score 0):

The things that you may try are:

- Search for optimization in Python. (Using python builtins might help!)
- Generally *list comprehensions* are better than *for loops*

My general advice is to use list comprehension with **Cython**. First utilize the list comprehension, and then check for Cython optimizations with the `.pyx` files and cythonize it.

Cython, in general, translates the python code to the C. Especially loops in Python works **significantly** faster with Cython. You can check one of the Sentdex's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXuEoqK4bEc&t=493s) explaining the general principles for cython. As you could see in the 23:20 of the video, it makes a significant change like ~100x faster than the traditional python loop.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I can use a `filter` for the path function and a list comprehension for the `check_domain_certs` function.  I'll also look at the video and Cython tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

In case the search fails more often than succeeds, this may be faster:

```
def check_domain_certs():
    all_paths_as_string = str(set(all_paths))
    for domain in all_domains:
        if not domain in all_paths_as_string:
            nocert_list.append(domain)
        else:
            cert_path = path(domain)  # full search returning cert path
            cert_check(cert_path)
            ...
```